# ROW_NUMBER OVER a new column

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-order-by, row-number

Is it possible to order by a new column inside row_number?
I would like to do something like this:

```
select text1 + text2 as NEW_TEXT, row_number over (order by NEW_TEXT) from table
```

but such sorting doesn't work (I get random results).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to repeat the expression `text1 + text2`

```
select text1 + text2 as NEW_TEXT, 
row_number() over (order by text1 + text2)
from table
```

Or do it in steps (foo could be a CTE here)

```
SELECT
    NEW_TEXT,
    row_number() over (order by NEW_TEXT)
FROM
    (
    select text1 + text2 as NEW_TEXT from table
    ) foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to wrap your initial results in a subselect and apply the `ROW_NUMBER` on this subselect.

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT  NEW_TEXT
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEW_TEXT)     
FROM    (       
            SELECT  text1 + text2 AS NEW_TEXT       
            FROM    [table]
        ) q
```

#### Test Data

```
;WITH [table] (text1, text2) AS (
    SELECT '1', '1'
    UNION ALL SELECT '1', '0'
    UNION ALL SELECT '2', '2'
    UNION ALL SELECT '2', '1'
)
SELECT  NEW_TEXT
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEW_TEXT)     
FROM    (       
            SELECT  text1 + text2 AS NEW_TEXT       
            FROM    [table]
        ) q
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using sub query like this way :

```
select NEW_TEXT, row_number() over (order by NEW_TEXT)
from
(
    select Text1 + Text2 as NEW_TEXT
    from TestTable
) TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select text1 + text2 as NEW_TEXT, 
row_number over (order by text1 + text2) 
from table
```